# FileNotFound exception while reading file from classpath in constructor argument in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, classpath, applicationcontext

I have a file mydoc.txt at the following location

```
C:/Tomcat6.0/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/classes/document/mydoc.txt
```

I have to get this file location through constructor injection and read the file.

```
public DocumentReader(String path) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
String line = null;
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  stringBuilder.append(line);
}
String doc = stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

I have configured the file location in applicationContext.xml as shown below.

```
<bean id="DocumentReader" class="com.myapp.DocumentReader" >
<constructor-arg  value="classpath:document/mydoc.txt"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

But, I am getting FileNotFound Exception while running the application. Is there any other way to read the file from this location ?

**Exception**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException:  classpath:document\mydoc.txt(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

Comment: Can you try keeping this file directly in WEB-INF /webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/mydoc.txt and then in the bean definition value is classpath:mydoc.txt

Comment: I think, your `document` directory already in `classpath`. So, you just need to configure ` value="classpath:mydoc.txt"`

Comment: @RaviKumar : i tried as you said but i am still getting the same exception **java.io.FileNotFoundException: classpath:mydoc.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)**

Comment: can you post the code of DocumentReader class

Comment: @RaviKumar : Added constructor code for DocumentReader class

Comment: keep the file mydoc.txt directly in WEB-INF and custructor value will be mydoc.txt. I think this should work

Comment: Your welcome! I just turned the comment into an answer, so you can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your constructor to take org.springframework.core.io.Resource instead of String.

If your constructor-argument is of type String, Spring inserts the value just like you wrote it down. Your FileReader then looks for a file named `mydoc.txt` in the folder `classpath:document` (which on some operating systems - like windows - is not even a valid folder-name)

If your constructor-argument is of type Ressource, Spring assumes that the String you are injecting is a Spring-Ressource-Path and resolves that for you.